# Pause YouTube video without having to switch to its Firefox tab

Tags: open-source, firefox, youtube

Sometimes to avoid external distractions at work I listen to YouTube videos playlists.

**QUESTION**: How to pause/play without having to switch to that YouTube tab?

Switching to the tab breaks my workflow, and music videos being displayed are potentially not safe for work.

Requirements:

- Minimal UI
- Compatible with latest Firefox
- Open source

Answer (score 3):

[Play/Pause](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/play-pause/) is a minimalistic Firefox extension that just adds a Play/Pause button to YouTube video tabs.

[image: Play/pause YouTube Firefox tab]

- License: MIT
- Source code: https://github.com/DanielKamkha/PlayPauseFirefox